# CoreNLP: How can I get only collapesed dependencies?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm parsing over 60,000 sentences with CoreNLP to get dependencies relations.

Because I only need collapsed dependencies, other dependencies types -- basic and collapsed-cc-processed -- are redundant for my own use, and make it hard to build my own codes, which take xml-output as input.

Can I get only collapsed dependencies?
If so, please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do this. Computing the additional representations take very little computation, and so they are always reported. They should be marked specially in the XML output, however; hopefully it's not hard to filter the correct representation in the downstream code.